# remove classes added by Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an accordion and Jquery is adding classes, I want to stop jquery to add some classes. how can I do that?
Below is the code but Jquery keeps on adding .ui-state-default to some visited elements.

```
if($check.hasClass('.ui-state-default')){
            $(this)('.columns > span').removeClass('ui-state-default');
            $(this)('.columns > span').addClass('ui-state-active');
        }else 
        {
            $(this)('.columns > span').removeClass('ui-state-active');
            $(this)('.columns > span').addClass('ui-state-default');
        }
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery UI widgets, it'll do that kind of thing a lot; that's important to the way the code is designed.  Perhaps you could explain **why** those classes are a problem for you; they really shouldn't hurt anything unless you've happened to already claim those exact same classes ...

Comment: In accordion I am trying to enable and disable sections if there is a condition where all the sections are enabled and I try to disable some of them I am not coz Jquery is adding ui-state-default class.

Comment: It still makes no sense; what's wrong with the elements having that class?  It's used by the jQuery UI CSS to create hover effects etc. Your code generally should **not** use those classes for state management; if you want to control things, make up your own classes.

Comment: since Jquery is adding .ui-state-default I am not able to disable that particular section.

Comment: How are you trying to "disable" it?

Comment: by adding class ui-state-default and removing ui-state-active.

Comment: @Jay - well the thing is that you simply cannot control the jQuery UI Accordion widget like that. It provides no mechanism for disabling one of the "folds", unless it's possible to stop a change via the "changestart" event handler.  I'll look at the source.

Comment: No, there doesn't seem to be any concept in the code of any of the "folds" being disabled. The "click" handlers installed by the plugin pay no attention to the the classes that are present on the parts of the accordion.

Answer (score 0):

As far as disabling the functionality of your accordion, see if this link has what you are looking for:

[how to disable certain links of jquery accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808134/how-to-disable-certain-links-of-jquery-accordion)

As far as your code, in your `hasClass`, you don't need the `.`, and your find contexts are created incorrectly:

```
var element = $(this).find('.columns > span');

if($check.hasClass('ui-state-default')) {
    element.removeClass('ui-state-default').addClass('ui-state-active');
} else {
    element.removeClass('ui-state-active').addClass('ui-state-default');
}
```

As far as maintaining state, using `.data` would make this process easier:

```
var elements = $(this).find('.columns > span'),
    enabled = element.data('enabled');

elements.each(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    if (element.data('enabled')) {
        element
            .data('enabled', false)
            .removeClass('ui-state-default')
            .addClass('ui-state-active');
    } else {
        element
            .data('enabled', true)
            .removeClass('ui-state-default')
            .addClass('ui-state-active');
    }
});
```

At any time, you can know if an element is enabled or disabled by checking the `.data('enabled')` data.

Comment: Actually I am enabling the sections with .ui-state-active and disabling with ui-state-default now when user is enabling/disabling sections I want to maintain the history of enabling/disabling.

Comment: This won't help - the problem is that the widget simply cannot be controlled by those classes; that's not at all what they're for.

Comment: is there a way I can check which div's Jquery added the class?

Comment: Are you asking about finding all the divs that have a certain class?

Comment: I mean what all divs Jquery has added the class to coz I have other classes too with ui-state-default.

Comment: `$('div.ui-state-default')` will select all `div`s that have a class of `ui-state-default`.