# Jquery - Accordion - active state

Tags: jquery-ui-accordion

I've searched for the answer on this forum, but haven't been able to find it.
Here is my question:

I want disable the possibility to open the first and the second pane of my accordion, and allow it to open only when if want. It's like to make some panes disabled and some enabled.

I've searched with this code :

```
$( "#accordion" ).bind( "accordionchangestart", function(event, ui) {                   
     var active = $(this).accordion( "option", "active" );
         if(active == 0)||(active == 1)){
    preventDefault();
     }                              
});
```

It works only for the second pane ( == 1) because when the state is closed, it's considered as false, and false == 0 for jquery.

I've tried searching if the selected pane is the first with the ui-state-active class, but this is too late, when the class appears, the pane is opened, and that's what i want to prevent.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery UI's Accordion than what you should do is use the **changestart** event to check which one is clicked and do whatever you want to do.

Use this to check the current state:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({changestart: function(event, ui) {
        alert(ui.newHeader[0].textContent);
}});
```

Yo can also change the current option like this:

```
$("#accordion").accordion("activate", 3);
```

You can find events documentation here:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#events

And here is the *activate* method documentation:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#method-activate

Comment: Thank you, but that's what i'm using in my code.
the problem is taht i can't dertermine if the pane clicked is the first one or not because false is considered as 0.

Comment: thanks but i don't know how tu use ui.newHeader // jQuery object, activated header. Would you please help me with a little bit of code ?

Comment: sorry again to bother you with my ignorance, but i am kind of noob.
how can i use ui.newHeader to know if it's the first pane ?
something like this ? if(ui.newHeader == 1) ?

Comment: @user1247956 Check my change in the answer. I think this would help you.

Comment: ui.newHeader[0] returns a node of the header element. With ui.newHeader[0].textContent you can get the title of the section. If this was helpful would you consider accepting my answer?

Comment: many thanks for your support.
I also combined it with this topic [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808134/how-to-disable-certain-links-of-jquery-accordion[/link]

Answer (score 0):

If I want to take action only when expanding:

```
var active = $(this.container).accordion('option', 'active');
if (!active && $.type(active) === 'boolean') {
  //No action
  return;
}
//Loading some data inside accordion content
```