# jQuery Accordion UI empty item issue.

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have problem with empty item(s) in accordion UI.

I have 3 sections.

```
+ Section 1
+ Section 2 (empty) 
+ Section 3
```

html

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>content 1</div>
  <h3>Section 2 (empty)</h3>
  <div></div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>content 3</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,       
    });
});​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ty5ZH/

When I click on `Section 2` an than click on other section, **accordion doesn't work**.

If I click on `Section 2` an than click on `Section 2` again a than click on other section everythigs works fine.

Is jQuery UI accordion bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop the section from even opening, this answer may be the fix you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4672074/750593

I created a JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/ty5ZH/2/ of it working. You need to add a class or ID to identify the sections that you don't want to open and then run the following immediately after declaring your accordian.

```
$('.disable').addClass("ui-state-disabled");
var accordion = $( "#accordion" ).data("accordion");
    accordion._std_clickHandler = accordion._clickHandler;
    accordion._clickHandler = function( event, target ) {
    var clicked = $( event.currentTarget || target );
    if (! clicked.hasClass("ui-state-disabled"))
        this._std_clickHandler(event, target);
    };
```

Comment: Yes. That it's. Thank you. My change: Automatic select empty items for disabling. http://jsfiddle.net/ty5ZH/5/

Answer (score 1):

This is a theming problem. You forgot to reference one of the jQuery UI CSS theme files, which is causing the issue.

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ty5ZH/1/).

Answer (score 1):

here is another solution.
you just need to use the  beforeActivate method to prevent it from expanding if empty.

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
    autoHeight: false,                                               
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
        if (ui.newPanel.length>0 && ui.newPanel.text()==""){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Using the above beforeActivate function helps in preventing the click & expand behavior for sections which are empty. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this combination, it will work fine.

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({
  heightStyle: "content"
});
```